# On Gaussian measures on spaces of continuous functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Denote by $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. Let $M$ be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of codimension 1 and denote by $C_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the subspace of $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ consisting of all functions that vanish on $M$.

Let $\mu$ be a centered Gaussian probability Borel measure on $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is $C_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Borel measurable as a subset of $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$? If yes, by a known zero-one law, its $\mu$-measure must be either 0 or 1. Is it 0 or 1? If not, does $C_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ contain (or is it contained in) a set of $\mu$-measure 0 or 1?